# Tile vector image as background

Tags: wpf, vector, background, tile

dear friends!
I have seamless vector image as canvas in my resource dictionary

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Canvas x:Key="SeamlessBackground" 
  ...   
</Canvas>
```

And I want to use it as my MainWindow background. I used VisualBrash:

```
<Window.Background>
    <VisualBrush Stretch="None" Visual="{StaticResource SeamlessBackground}" TileMode="Tile" >
        <VisualBrush.Transform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.2" ScaleY="0.2"/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </VisualBrush.Transform>
    </VisualBrush>
</Window.Background>
```

But instead of big seamless background, I get several separated images with huge seams between them. And when I stretch my form these seams are growth. I expected that when I stretch form new images will drown to fill up this seams.
Please help)))

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself)))

The key is Absolute units in ViewPort instead of Relative:

```
<Window.Background>
    <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource SeamlessBackground}" TileMode="Tile" 
      ViewportUnits="Absolute" 
      Viewport="0,0,100,100"/>
</Window.Background>
```